# Node.js - hash alghoritms implementation

Tags: node.js, md5, sha256, whirlpool

I have a question, is there any module that contains implementations of all hashing algorithms? I mainly care about MD5, SHA-256 and Whirlpool.

I heard about the crypto module, but I can't find if it has the Whirlpool algorithm.

If there is a solution in another programming language then please write one that offers it. I want the module or library to contain all 3 algorithms that I listed.

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/crypto.html#cryptogethashes

Comment: Yes, there is no info about Whirlpool, only MD5 and SHA-256

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details. What OS/node version are u using? In mine v16 LTS i have a whirlpool digest. `console.log(require("crypto").getHashes().includes("whirlpool"));`

Comment: My node version is: v18.17.0 and it actually doesn't work. I downgrade version to 16.20.1 and now it's fine. Thank you @Marc